# My UK Visa has been issued with a date of expiry that is earlier than my dates of travel. How can I fix it?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, visa-extensions

I recently applied for a visitors visa to take a PLAB exam on 6 July; my visa was issued to expire on 4 July!

I contacted them via email and phone and all they did was tell me that they escalated the issue; it has been 2 weeks and no one contacted me.

1. Can this be fixed without applying for an extension?
2. Can it be fixed while I'm in the UK because I need to go there to audit some courses?
3. If I apply for an extension, will I be able to travel to and from the UK for the extended period or it will extend my ongoing visit only?

Comment: There is a chance to fix it in the UK depending upon how you applied originally

Comment: Read https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66829/extending-an-uk-c-visit-visa-do-i-need-brp?rq=1